# jQuery selected options

Tags: jquery, switch-statement

I have a dropdownlist that is being filtered (example..(toggleOptionVisibility puts a span around the option, if true, span is visible)):

```
case 'Actimel drank naturel':
            $(eenheid + ' option[value="101"]').toggleOptionVisibility( true );
            $(eenheid + ' option[value="102"]').toggleOptionVisibility( true );
            $(eenheid + ' option[value="103"]').toggleOptionVisibility( true );
            $(eenheid + ' option[value="116"]').toggleOptionVisibility( true );
            break;
case 'Roosvicee multivit (siroop)':
            $(eenheid + ' option[value="101"]').toggleOptionVisibility( true );
            $(eenheid + ' option[value="102"]').toggleOptionVisibility( true );
            $(eenheid + ' option[value="103"]').toggleOptionVisibility( true );
            $(eenheid + ' option[value="104"]').toggleOptionVisibility( true );
            $(eenheid + ' option[value="111"]').toggleOptionVisibility( true );
            $(eenheid + ' option[value="116"]').toggleOptionVisibility( true );
            break;
```

Filtering works, just showing an example as to how I do it.

now the problem is, that whatever I choose when I submit the form, the selected="selected" is whatever was chosen by the user (it works in IE), but the dropdownlist itself displays the second last value in Firefox and the last value in Chrome.

The selected="selected" remains what the user input was, even in firefox and chrome.

And here's my question, does any of you know why this is happening, why it works in IE and not chrome / firefox?

Because everyone likes code, I'll post a little bit more.

```
$(eenheid + ' option').toggleOptionVisibility( false );
```

To hide all options before being filtered to make sure only the filtered options show.

Answer (score 1):

For the `<span>` around `<option>` discuss :

```
interface HTMLSelectElement : HTMLElement {
    ...
    readonly attribute HTMLCollection selectedOptions;
    ...
};
```

`selectedOptions` must be a list of `<option>` or `<optgroup>` for maximum compatibility. It's not forbidden to use `<span>` but at **your own risk**.

see http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-select-element

Comment: I got it fixed by removing the options and storing them in a varable. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('select option[value="..."]').toggleOptionVisibility(false);
$('select').val($('#select-test > option:first'));
```

To get selected value :

```
$('select option:selected').val()
```

**Example :** http://jsfiddle.net/d3FuV/5/

Comment: As I said, filtering works fine, there's no problem there, but .prop('disabled' , true); doesn't work in IE / safari. that's why I did it with the toggleOptionVisibility

Comment: in IE, the disabled value just shows disabled, it's not gone.

Comment: I just updated my post. The new jsfiddle link is working in Chrome, IE & Safari. The disabled values are still visible in IE / Safari, they does not support `display: none` on `select option`. If you want not to see them, you should `.remove()` and keep it in a variable if needed.

Comment: My function toggleOptionVisibility is working perfectly fine, it filters whatever it needs to filter, everything shows fine, it's just that Firefox and Chrome DO have the right selected value, but they dont display the selected value. IE does display the right selected value, if you want, I can show you what I mean, the site I'm trying it out on is live.

Comment: Tested in Chrome, IE & Safari. But I keep saying that using `span` around `option` is not a good idea.

Comment: As I keeep saying.. the span is not the problem, the DDL gets filtered with 4 options, user selects one, submits form, the selected option is what the user selected, but the value that shows one of the other 4 options (the DDL still being filtered by 4 options)

Comment: Please check the last jsfiddle link. The span is the problem for html/js interpretation. `$('select option:selected').val()` is the workaround for your issue (don't use `$('select').val()`). You also have to set the real value at $(document).ready() with `$('select').val($('#select-test > option:first'));`